# SonarLint not working for coverage and duplications?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarlint

I am using Sonar-Lint as my static code analysis plugin in intellij. When I run that after setting configurations, it can fetch rules form the server and show issues.

But still it can't clearly indicate code-duplication and coverage. Can anyone tell me, what has gone wrong or it's a bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SonarLint doesn't support those features, it goes out of its scope as SonarLint won't necessarily scan the entire project. SonarLint only shows code issues.

Use SonarQube and one of its Scanners to have that information.

Comment: So would we be having those features in future?

Comment: No. The primary goal of SonarLint is to show issues as you code, not to analyze the entire project to get coverage or duplication.

Comment: make sense then :)

Comment: But lets say my build process integrates code coverage using coverlet for example, that data is shown on SonarQube, but unfortunately not visualised using SonarLint. Still think would be a great addition